# Is there any way to change the default port of selenoid-ui from 8080 to other ports

Tags: selenoid

Is there any way we can change default port os selenoid-ui from 8080 to some other port? I've tried as below in yml file but no success. With this configuration selenoid-ui neither works with 8080 nor 8181,

selenoid-ui:
        image: "aerokube/selenoid-ui"
        network_mode: bridge
        links:
        - selenoid
            command: ["--selenoid-uri", "http://selenoid:4444"]
            command: ["--listen",":8081"]

I have read in few posts about using cm tool to start selenoid-ui with different port. But is it possible to make it in docker-compose yml file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Selenoid UI is just a regular web-service by default listening on port 8080. Having said that you have several options:

1) When running as a binary simply use `-listen` flag as follows:

```
$ ./selenoid-ui -listen :8081
```

2) When running as Docker container it is better to use port mapping:

```
$ docker run -d --name selenoid-ui -p 8081:8080 aerokube/selenoid-ui:latest-release
```