# Selenoid UI is not getting launched on 8081 port when I am creating infrastructure through docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, selenium-grid, selenoid

**docker-compose.yml file**

```
version: '3'
services:
  selenoid:
    image: "aerokube/selenoid:latest"
    container_name: selenoid
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    networks:
      - selenoid
    volumes:
      - ".:/etc/selenoid"
      - "./target:/output"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "./target:/opt/selenoid/video"
    environment:
      - "OVERRIDE_VIDEO_OUTPUT_DIR=$PWD/target"
    command: ["-conf", "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json", "-video-output-dir", "/opt/selenoid/video", "-container-network", "selenoid"]
  selenoid-ui:
    image: "aerokube/selenoid-ui:latest"
    container_name: selenoid-ui
    links:
      - selenoid
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    networks:
      - selenoid
    command: ["--selenoid-uri", "http://selenoid:4444"]
  
  chrome_89.0:
    image: "selenoid/vnc:chrome_89.0"
    container_name: chrome_89.0
    links:
      - selenoid
      - selenoid-ui
    depends_on:
      - selenoid
      - selenoid-ui
    networks:
      - selenoid
    volumes:
      - "/dev/shm:/dev/shm"
  chrome_91.0:
    image: "selenoid/vnc:chrome_91.0"
    container_name: chrome_91.0
    links:
      - selenoid
      - selenoid-ui
    depends_on:
      - selenoid
      - selenoid-ui
    networks:
      - selenoid
    volumes:
      - "/dev/shm:/dev/shm" 
  firefox_57.0:
    image: "selenoid/vnc:firefox_57.0"
    container_name: firefox_57.0
    links:
      - selenoid
      - selenoid-ui
    depends_on:
      - selenoid
      - selenoid-ui
    networks:
      - selenoid
    volumes:
      - "/dev/shm:/dev/shm"
  firefox_83.0:
    image: "selenoid/vnc:firefox_83.0"
    container_name: firefox_83.0
    links:
      - selenoid
      - selenoid-ui
    depends_on:
      - selenoid
      - selenoid-ui
    networks:
      - selenoid
    volumes:
      - "/dev/shm:/dev/shm"            
networks:
  selenoid:
    external:
      name: selenoid
```

**browser.json file**

```
{
  "firefox": {
    "default": "57.0",

        "versions": {
            "57.0": {
                "image": "selenoid/vnc:firefox_57.0",
                "port": "4444",
                "path": "/wd/hub"
            }
        },
        "versions": {
            "83.0": {
                "image": "selenoid/vnc:firefox_83.0",
                "port": "4444",
                "path": "/wd/hub"
            }
        }

    },
  "chrome": {
    "default": "latest",

    "versions": {
            "89.0": {
                "image": "selenoid/vnc:chrome_89.0",
                "port": "4444",
                "path": "/"
            }
        },
        "versions": {
            "91.0": {
                "image": "selenoid/vnc:chrome_91.0",
                "port": "4444",
                "path": "/"
            }
        }

  }
}
```

Executing below commands in sequence:

- **docker network create selenoid** command
- **docker-compose up -d** command
- **docker ps -a**

All the containers are running up.

When I tried to launch localhost:8081 for selenoid UI, it's not working as expected.

I want to run my selenoid UI on 8081 only as 8080 port is occupied by my local Jenkins.

Please let me know if I am missing any configuration and how can I access selenoid UI on 8081 port.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the selenoid UI port in the docker-compose service to map to port 8080 like:

```
  selenoid-ui:
      image: "aerokube/selenoid-ui:latest"
      container_name: selenoid-ui
      links:
          - selenoid
      ports:
          - "8081:8080"
```

Or you just change the port that it is listening like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60435982/1563297) answer passing the parameter:

`-listen :8081`

Comment: If that helps please consider marking as answered, upvote, etc etc.... Tks